# How to auto refresh a tree region

Tags: oracle-apex

Is possible to automatically refresh a tree region? Only this region. I was trying the same way to refresh reports but it doesn't work.

Comment: You havn't provided enough information.

Comment: @Nathan what information do you need? I'm using apex 4 in oracle XE and i have a region which have a tree inside...i want to refresh it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this blog: http://application-express-blog.e-dba.com/?tag=apex-tree

Maybe it will help you.

Especially this one: http://application-express-blog.e-dba.com/?p=1219

You need an AJAX version of the tree.

Comment: @TaesungShin has posted that option to me but the post has disappear from here. That is not my solution because it will change me visual of the tree and the page